# Handling range in CNAME

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, nginx, cname-record

We have different set of CNAMEs pointing to different `subdomains`. These `subdomains` (a.domain.com, b.domain.com) are pointing to different IPs on different machines.

```
# Server A
a1.domain.com pointing to a.domain.com
a2.domain.com pointing to a.domain.com
..
aN.domain.com pointing to a.domain.com

# Server B
b1.domain.com pointing to b.domain.com
b2.domain.com pointing to b.domain.com
..
bN.domain.com pointing to b.domain.com
```

Currently, we have to add individual CNAME entries (eg. a1... aN) against a single subdomain (a.dominan.com). We repeat the above process for every new server which is actually another subdomain (e.g. c.domain.com). Is there a way we can specify a range of CNAMEs (e.g. [a1..a25].domain.com point to a.domain.com) instead of adding separate CNAME etnries?

Is there any possibility to handle this at DNS or webserver (apache or Nginx) level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to handle this in both DNS (if you are using BIND) and Apache (partially)/nginx (fully).

**BIND** supports the [$GENERATE](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/generate.html) keyword and you can do the following:

```
$GENERATE 1-10 a$.domain.com CNAME a.domain.com
```

In **Apache** you can only use a wildcard for [ServerAlias](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2007/01/06/using-wildcards-in-apache-server-aliases/), not a regular expression:

```
ServerAlias a*.domain.com
```

In **nginx** you can use a regular expression for [server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html):

```
server_name ~^a[1-10]\.domain\.com$;
```

Comment: Vladimir, thanks for precise and comprehensive answer. I have a starting point now and will look into it further to figure out which servers our needs best. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

DNS has only one wildcard: `*`

There's nothing wrong with listing all of those entries in a zone file.

I'm pretty sure Apache can't do ranges like that in `ServerAlias` directives but it wouldn't surprise me if nginx could handle regexes in its `server` directive.

You could *generate* your web server config or your DNS config by using `seq 1 25` or a tool such as puppet if typing them all out by hand is too onerous.

You could also do this at the application level if all these different domains should be running the same app.  (That's how the company I work for does it.)

Answer (score 1):

A BIND specific answer has already been given; but in case anyone has the same problem with a different server and only has access to the basics, my thought would be to change the addresses to X.a.domain.com / X.b.domain.com, and then use the * wildcard